# Unable to connect to Dynamics CRM 2013 from Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have an event receiver in SharePoint and this needs to communicate with Dynamics CRM 2013. It basically checks that user owns the record and if it doesn't creates a task for the record owner.

The problem is that it times out on instantiation of OrganizationServiceProxy, basically on this line:

```
 var service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(url, null, creds, null);
```

I have checked using various browsers that I can get to the Dynamics CRM server, so this is definitely not a problem with networks/firewall.

It seems as if the remote call is being blocked, but blocked by what? I'm guessing some sort of setting on Sharepoint but I don't really know

Anybody knows how to sort this out?

Comment: Have you opened Fiddler on the machine that you are connecting from to see what the response status is?

Comment: it seems to be related to the certificates that SP will trust as it works fine when accessing Dynamics via the http endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution can be found here:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135723/cant-make-remote-requests-from-sharepoint-2013-event-receiver

> make sure you have all of the certs in the certification path of the ssl certificate for the dynamics url loaded into the SharePoint trust center.